# Cloudinary $.cloudinary.unsigned_upload_tag is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloudinary

I'm trying to do cloudinary unsigned uploads. I have the file tag in html, and now I'm trying to initialize it via JavaScript. However, I'm recieving wonderful errors, that state `$.cloudinary.unsigned_upload_tag is not a function`. Here's the revelant code:

Library inclusions

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/master/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cloudinary/pkg-cloudinary-jquery/master/cloudinary-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Upload tag

```
<input type="file" id="selectedFile" style=""  />
```

Initializing JS

```
$.cloudinary.config( { cloud_name: "wearnator"});
$("#selectedFile").append($.cloudinary.unsigned_upload_tag("af8fvvkw",{ cloud_name: 'wearnator' }));
```

The error is on the append line. More curiously, whenever I select a file, the upload **is** triggerred, but it uploads the sample picture of flowers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input field should include a `name="file"` attribute:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="selectedFile" />
```

And the JS initializing should be:

```
$("#selectedFile").unsigned_cloudinary_upload("af8fvvkw",{ cloud_name: 'wearnator' });
```

Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: Still getting the sample picture uploaded. Also the same error

Comment: Can you share a URL to a live webpage that demonstrates this?

Comment: I could. I'll set one up later on.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, this indeed helped understanding the issue. Note that you included the `cloudinary-jquery` library which only supports basic jQuery actions, like URLs generation. In order to perform file uploads, you need to include the `cloudinary-jquery-file-upload` library instead. For more information: https://github.com/cloudinary/pkg-cloudinary-jquery-file-upload